# Edit Auto Update Admin Notification

Tags: admin, notifications, automatic-updates

I'm new on stackexchange.com and hope to get some help for my topic.
If a WordPRess website uses auto update the admin gets a notification, after the auto update is done.
My goal is to change the notification text. What I'm looking for is a filter or hook or any other way to change this text individually, maybe within the functions.php of a theme.
Can someone point me to the right function/hook/filter (or what ever)?!

Thank a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try [auto_core_update_email](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/auto_core_update_email/). E.g:

```
add_filter('auto_core_update_email', function($email, $type, $core_update, $result)
{
  if ('success' === $type)
    $email['body'] = sprintf( __('Congratulation! Your site at %1$s has been updated automatically to WordPress %2$s.', 'textdomain'), home_url(), $core_update->current ) . "\n\n";

  return $email;
}, PHP_INT_MAX, 4);
```

Comment: Thank you! Not sure why this can work :-) but will give it a try and leave a result in the next days.